# Getting the longest sequence of the same elements from 2D Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

The method public List horizontalSequences() return the list of the longest sequence of the same elements in a horizontal row. For example, if I have

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = [. . . c c . 

                                     a a a a . . 

                                     b b b b b b 

                                     z z . c c c 
                                                ]
```

then the method should return the list containing all 6 `b`s (`[b,b,b,b,b,b]`). I'm really stuck in this problem and would appreciate if smb could take a look at the code. I dont think my code logic is correct and it's not working properly at all. But what if I have this list:
 ArrayList> list =

```
                                    [. . .  c . 

                                     . . . a . . 

                                     . . . . . . 

                                     . . . c . . 
                                                ]
```

then the method should return only the first occurence, i.e. the first element in the list which is `[c]`.
 Thanks in advance!

```
public List<String> gorizontalSequence(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list){
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     int currentCount = 0;
     int max = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size() - 2;){

             if(list.get(i).get(j).equals(list.get(i).get(j-1)) 
                     && (!(list.get(i).get(j).equals("."))) 
                             && (!(list.get(i).get(j-1).equals(".")))){


                 currentCount+=2;
                 if(currentCount > max){
                     max = currentCount;
                 }

                 //list.clear();
                 list.add(list.get(i).get(j-1));
                 list.add(list.get(i).get(j));
                 j+=2;

             }

             else{
             list.add(list.get(i).get(j-1));
             currentCount++;
             if(currentCount > max){
                 max = currentCount;
            } 
                 j++;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Do all of the elements in the inner lists represent a single character (as your example data implies)? I.e could you model the data with `List<String> list`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, it can be anything only of type String - any length. But the goal is to return the longest sequence of the same element in a list

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is - you want to find the maximum sequence of a letter occuring. I won't write the entire program for you but there is a way to do this in one iteration:

### Approach

We are going to, as we iterate through the list, save the current letter's value in a temp variable. Then we are going to see if the next one is also the temp variable. If that is the case, we increment to a temporary variable holding the # of consecutive letters. If it isn't the case, we check if that temporary variable is bigger than the max sequence(stored in another variable). If it is, we override max and set the temp var to 0, if not, we just set it to 0 and start again.

#### Pseudocode

```
//I will assume it's an array for now
char currentChar = list[0]
int maxSeq, maxIndex
int curSeq 
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    char = list[i]
    if currentChar == c
        curSeq++
    else
        if curSeq > maxSeq //ONLY if it's greater. If it's equal to then we will get the LAST sequence max
            maxSeq = curSeq
            maxIndex = i
            curSeq = 0
        else 
            curSeq = 0

//now you have the index at which it starts and the length of the sequence
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I get the idea, but is it okay to do 2d Arraylist with one loop ? @OneRaynyDay

Comment: @john it's not, but I didn't know it was 2d. No problem though, just apply the same algorithm to each row if you want to know the maximum sequence in each row. If you want to know the max sequence row just test that in your outer for loop. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
public ArrayList<String> horizontalSequence(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list)
{
    String maxString = "";
    int currentCount;
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        currentCount = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if(list.get(i).get(j).equals("."))
            {
                currentCount = 1;
                continue;
            }

            if(list.get(i).get(j).equals(list.get(i).get(j+1)))
            {
                currentCount++;
            }

            if( max <currentCount ) {
                max = currentCount;
                maxString = list.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(max, maxString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correct it is 'given a list of lists, find the longest consecutive sequence of equal elements in any one list'. That is the consecutive sequence can't be split across lists.

If that's the case then you can do it in two steps:

1. For each list, reduce to the longest sequence within that list.
2. Find the longest of those lists.

So the first problem is given a list of elements, what's the longest consecutive sequence within that list.

```
private static <E> List<E> longestConsecutiveSequence(List<E> list) {
    List<E> longestSequence = new ArrayList<>();
    List<E> currentSequence = new ArrayList<>();
    for (E el: list) {
        if (!currentSequence.isEmpty() && !e.equals(currentSequence.get(0)))
            currentSequence = new ArrayList<>();
        currentSequence.add(e);
        if (currentSequence.size() > longestSequence.size())
            longestSequence = currentSequence;
    }
    return longestSequence;
}
```

And the second problem is to find the longest list:

```
public static <E> List<E> longestConsecutiveSequence(List<List<E>> listOfLists) {
    List<E> longestSequence = null;
    for (List<E> list: listOfLists) {
        List<E> sequence = longestConsecutiveSequence(list);
        if (longestSequence == null || sequence.size() > longestSequence.size())
            longestSequence = sequence;
    }
    return longestSequence;
}
```

Note that if you are using Java 8 then things get a lot simpler. For example the second method becomes:

```
return listOfList.stream()
    .map(this::longestConsecutiveSequence)
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size));
```

The first one can also be done with streams but it's a bit trickier because Java streams are intended for independent processing of items so checking sequences is non-trivial. Let me know if you want me to post that or if it's too much detail.

Answer (score 0):

Create an int array with same size with your list to save "point" of an element.
If current element equals previous element, its point is previous element point plus 1.
Get the max point plus 1, we have the max range size

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("v", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a");
    int[] points = new int[list.size()];
    int maxPos = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1)))
            points[i] = points[i - 1] + 1;
        if (points[i] > points[maxPos])
            maxPos = i;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
    System.out.println("Max range size: " + (points[maxPos] + 1));
    System.out.println("With element: " + list.get(maxPos));
```

Now you can create an ArrayList with size of **`points[maxPos] + 1`** and add elements of **`list.get(maxPos)`**